# TypeScript: Intersection Types for construct signature and a type doesn't work, but for call signature and a type does

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I would like to create an intersection type, which consists of a constructor signature and some other type.

```
type CustomMixer<T1, T2> = (new (...args: any[]) => T1) & T2
```

> Generelly I need this to annotate the return type of a function, which sets some static methods to a Class(*Function*), like `Object.assign(MyCtorFn, staticMethods)`

TypeScript allows to create such types, return it, but I can't then initialize the type with the `new` keyword.

```
const MyType: CustomMixer<Foo, Bar> = someFactoryFunction()
const x = new MyType()
```

> Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

**But**, if `CustomMixer` intersection consists of a call signature and other type, then everything works as expected.

```
type CustomMixer<T1, T2> = ((...args: any[]) => T1) & T2
const MyType: CustomMixer<Foo, Bar> = someFactoryFunction()
MyType.| // Autocompletion for T2 works
const x = MyType()
x.|// Autocompletion for T1 works
```

Here is the link to [TS Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=namespace%20DoesntWork%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20isFoo%20()%20%7B%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Baz%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20isBaz%20()%20%7B%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20type%20CustomMixer%3CT1%2C%20T2%3E%20%3D%20(new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T1)%20%26%20T2%0A%0A%20%20%20%20function%20CustomMixerFactory%3CT1%2C%20T2%3E()%3A%20CustomMixer%3CT1%2C%20T2%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Mimic%20typed%20return%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%20as%20CustomMixer%3CT1%2C%20T2%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20const%20MyType%20%3D%20CustomMixerFactory%3CFoo%2C%20Baz%3E()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20is%20OK%0A%20%20%20%20MyType.isBaz()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Cannot%20use%20'new'%20with%20an%20expression%20whose%20type%20lacks%20a%20call%20or%20construct%20signature.%0A%20%20%20%20let%20myType%20%3D%20new%20MyType()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Anamespace%20Works%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20isFoo%20()%20%7B%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Baz%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20isBaz%20()%20%7B%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20type%20CustomMixer%3CT1%2C%20T2%3E%20%3D%20(%2F*new*%2F%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T1)%20%26%20T2%0A%0A%20%20%20%20function%20CustomMixerFactory%3CT1%2C%20T2%3E()%3A%20CustomMixer%3CT1%2C%20T2%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%20as%20CustomMixer%3CT1%2C%20T2%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20const%20MyType%20%3D%20CustomMixerFactory%3CFoo%2C%20Baz%3E()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20is%20OK%0A%20%20%20%20MyType.isBaz()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20is%20OK%0A%20%20%20%20let%20myType%20%3D%20MyType()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20is%20OK%0A%20%20%20%20myType.isFoo()%3B%0A%7D%0A)

Is it possible to make the first example work?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
type CustomMixer<T1, T2> = T1 & T2;

function CustomMixerFactory<T1, T2>(): CustomMixer<T1, T2> {
    // Mimic typed return
    return null as CustomMixer<T1, T2>;
}

const MyType = CustomMixerFactory<typeof Foo, Baz>();

MyType.isBaz(); // fine
let myType = new MyType(); // fine
myType.isFoo(); // fine
```

Comment: Thank you, with the solution I even better undestand the type system in TypeScript.